# Rsync is not deleting files and complains of "No space left on device (28)"

Tags: mac, video, backup, rsync

I am using `rsync` (2.6.9, protocol version 29) on macOS 10.14.6 (Mojave) to backup a disk with videos. The source has 999GB capacity with 75GB free and the backup has 1TB capacity. The command is:

```
$ rsync -avxW --progress /Volumes/Video/ /Volumes/Video\ backup/
building file list ... 
40989 files to consider
.DS_Store
       26628 100%    0.00kB/s    0:00:00 (xfer#1, to-check=40987/40989)
.DocumentRevisions-V100/
.Spotlight-V100/
rsync: failed to set times on "/Volumes/Video backup/.Spotlight-V100": Operation not permitted (1)
.fseventsd/
iMovie Library.imovielibrary/movie/Original Media/
iMovie Library.imovielibrary/movie/Original Media/DSC_0004.mov
rsync: writefd_unbuffered failed to write 32768 bytes [sender]: Broken pipe (32)
rsync: write failed on "/Volumes/Video backup/iMovie Library.imovielibrary/movie/Original Media/DSC_0004.mov": No space left on device (28)
rsync error: error in file IO (code 11) at /BuildRoot/Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/rsync/rsync-52.200.1/rsync/receiver.c(268) [receiver=2.6.9]
rsync: connection unexpectedly closed (76 bytes received so far) [sender]
rsync error: error in rsync protocol data stream (code 12) at /BuildRoot/Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/rsync/rsync-52.200.1/rsync/io.c(453) [sender=2.6.9]
```

The backup disk is full because `rsync` did not delete several files that are now missing from the original. I checked that the option `--delete-before` is the default and I also tried with `--delete` to remove extraneous files, but got the same error with the same file.

How can I make a perfect clone of a disk with `rsync`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For lack of a neat solution, I coded a hack in Python to walk through the target and delete the files and directories that do not exist in the source.

Make sure that you don't accidentally swap source and target, or you'll lose the original files. The order is the same as `rsync`: first source and then target.

By default the code prompts for confirmation before deleting the first five paths, so you can verify that you are not deleting the source. It deletes files in the target that are symlinks in the source.

Use with:

```bsh
python3 rsync_pre_process.py /Volumes/source /Volumes/target
```

You can then run `rsync` with, for example as below (and `-a` preserves symlinks):

```bsh
rsync -avxW --delete --delete-before --progress /Volumes/source /Volumes/target
```

Here is the code for `rsync_pre_process.py`:

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python3
# 
# Usage: python3 rsync_pre_process.py /Volumes/source /Volumes/target [5]
#
# You can then run: rsync -avxW --delete --delete-before --progress /Volumes/source /Volumes/target
# 
# This code deletes files present in the target that are missing from the
# source. It circumvents one case of rsync's error "No space left on device
# (28)" even though you may run rsync with `-delete` and `--delete-before`.
#
# It prompts for confirmation to delete a certain number of files or
# directories, 5 by default, before deleting files without confirmation.
#
# It removes files in the target that are symlinks in the source.
#
# author: Miguel Morin
# copyright: public domain
# year: 2019

import os
import pathlib
import shutil
import sys

MAX_VERIFICATIONS = 5

def remove(path, verify):
    """Removes a file or directory, asking for confirmation first if requested."""
    if verify:
        print(path)
        print("Remove this file? Press RET to proceed, C-c to abort.")
        sys.stdin.read(1)
    p = pathlib.Path(path)
    if os.path.islink(path) or not p.is_dir():
        os.remove(path)
    else:
        try:
            # shutil.rmtree instead of os.remove() because the former works in
            # iMovie folders where the latter throws an error, `PermissionError:
            # [Errno 1] Operation not permitted:`
            shutil.rmtree(path)
        except PermissionError as e:
            print("Unable to remove '%s' due to permission error" % path)

def cleanup(source, target, max_verifications):
    """Deletes all files from the target that are missing from the source, prompting 
    confirmations up to `max_verifications`.
    """
    num_verifications = 0
    for root, dirs, files in os.walk(target, topdown = False):
        for name in files + dirs:
            verify = num_verifications < max_verifications
            target_filepath = os.path.join(root, name)
            source_filepath = target_filepath.replace(target, source)
            if not os.path.exists(source_filepath) or os.path.islink(source_filepath):
                remove(target_filepath, verify)
                num_verifications += 1

def main():
    source = sys.argv[1]
    target = sys.argv[2]

    if not (source and target):
        raise ValueError("You must supply source and target arguments. Your arguments: " + str(argv[1:]))

    if 4 == len(sys.argv):
        max_verifications = int(sys.argv[3])
    else:
        max_verifications = MAX_VERIFICATIONS

    cleanup(source = source, target = target, max_verifications = max_verifications)

if "__main__" == __name__:
    main()
```